# Tracking the userID

Tags: nodes, forms

Where can I find the code where Drupal sends strings (such as the userID) from a content submission page to the node table in the database?

If you know of a guide that explains the Drupal content submission process, please share it!

edit: I'll try to explain what my goal is.

I have added a new field to the article content type that is using an integer field type. when users add content, they submit a number in the new field. I would like to perform a calculation before that number is sent to the database. I hope this is more descriptive of the task I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, you can use a custom module and hook_node_presave($node),

For more information, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7

If you have trouble understanding what I mean, shout :)

Comment: I'm running into an issue when using the function to change a node title. Here's the code: <?php function hook_node_presave($node) { if ($node->title = 'please') { $node->title = 'thank you'; } }

Comment: My issue is that the title is not changing after submitting the content.

Comment: Create a module, call it mymodule...then enable the module.
So the function that you should create will be called mymodule_node_presave($node) .

It should be working.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I've run into another issue when assigning a string to $node->title. I've tried  $node->title = 0; which works, but  $node->title = $foo; and  $node->title = "$foo"; returns 'Recoverable fatal error: object of class DatabaseStatementBase could not be converted to string..'. I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1439236

Can you try any suggestions from there ?